# Docker build error: - npm ERR! Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: node.js, docker, npm

I want to create docker image using below Dockerfile, but gives me "**npm ERR! Maximum call stack size exceeded**" error but the same dockerfile if I run in my local mac machine it works fine.

Dockerfile :-

```
FROM node:10
WORKDIR /usr/src/app/
#COPY package*.json /usr/src/app/
COPY . /usr/src/app/
RUN npm install
```

Files available in the Dockerfiles folder are :-

```
Dockerfile  README.md  codegen.yml  package-lock.json  package.json  public  src  tsconfig.json
```

My Host System Specification:-

```
[root@workspace-frontend]# free -h
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:            15G        3.6G        840M        141M         11G         12G
Swap:            0B          0B          0B
```

Host operation system:-

```
Operating System: Amazon Linux 2
```

Note :- I already delete package-lock.json and check the status but it won't work for me.

Comment: try to use `yarn`

Comment: Any other solution ?

Comment: @me25 how did you solve this. Run into the same issue also with Amazon Linux 2 instance. Docker buildl is working locally on mac